# Starcraft Installation asks for a mythical Disk 2

Tags: starcraft

I just purchased the Starcraft Battle Chest containing Starcraft and BroodWar.  When I try to install Starcraft I get halfway through and I'm prompted to "Insert Disk 2".  The box did not contain a second disk.  My computer is Windows 7 (x64). What do I need to do to continue?

**Box Contents:**

- Starcraft Disk
- Broodwar Disk
- WoW Trial Disk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> After you install the Original version of Starcraft, take the CD out, and put in the Brood War Starcraft CD in and it will finish up the loading.

[Source](http://www.gamespot.com/pc/strategy/starcraft/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-47547839&pid=25418)

Comment: You can also download it directly from the battle.net website. Once you log in, go to account, and under Classic Games, click the Starcraft Anthology. This page has links to download the game client for either Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After you install the original version of Starcraft take the CD out and put in the Brood War Starcraft CD and it will continue installing.

This works but if you tried to install it before you must erase the Starcraft's files and start again with the first and then the Brood War CD.