# Starcraft 1 disc 2 isn't continuing the installation

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, starcraft

A couple years ago I bought Starcraft Battle Chest. I got a new computer and I'm trying to install it. The problem is that it gets halfway there, and tells me to insert disc 2. But when I insert Brood War it brings up the Brood War installer instead of continuing the installation. If I try to install using the Brood War installer it says that i have to have the original installed. If I close the Brood War installer it just stays at 51%. I am on Windows 7 64 bit if it matters.

Comment: It sounds like it's asking for disc 2 of the base game. I don't remember there being more than one disc, though...

Comment: There was definitely only one CD for SC and one CD for SC:BW.

Comment: There was a [similar (actually same question) asked](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4825/47872) where the answer given was to insert the Brood War disc. It was selected as the best answer, but there were no indications on if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't answering your question directly, but on the CD case for the original Starcraft (should be the first disc) there should be a 13 digit cd key.

If you try downloading the Starcraft installer from Blizzard, you wont require the discs to play the game. You will be able to launch them straight from your desktop. However, that game requires a 26 digit key. Blizzard allows you to register you 13 digit cd key to an account to receive a 26 digit key which you can use to use the downloaded installer.

You can log in or register at https://us.battle.net/login/en/. Once you log in select the "Games & Codes" menu and from there select "Add a Game Key." Enter your 13 digit code and you will then receive your license key which allows  you to download the game.

---

On a side note, when I bought my Battle Chest (12 years ago), the first disc was StarCraft and the second disc was the Brood War Expansion. Starcraft should install independent of Brood War while Brood War depends on Starcraft, much in the way that Heart of the Swarm and Legacy of the Void expansions for Starcraft II require that you own Starcraft II: Wings of Liberty. It may be the case that the newer Starcraft BattleChest comes with a different set up now, but if it was like how I had it, you shouldn't need to switch discs.

Comment: Well I have capped internet so I can't do that. Also around 2009 the battle chests make you install both for some reason. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry, I tried googling to see how other people handled the problem, but it turns out everyone else just fell back on the same fall back solution as I suggested. The other results from google were scrapings of your question stolen and put on other sites...Blizzard is infamous for their lack of support on their products, it seems that there is a defect with the battlechest that Blizzard doesn't want to fix.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll lug my desktop up to McDonalds in town, then use your solution. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: Ugh, blizzards forums are worse. They suggest the same thing. No way to submit a new support ticket with them either for legacy games. Sorry, I'll keep looking for solutions, but Blizzard is irritating. I believe the installer is a 200mb download, plus you need to download the patch separately (Blizzard didn't bother to integrate the patch into the downloadable version, go figure).